# How to return the callback of .fail() if the return dataType is not a html?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-1.9

How can I return the callback of **.fail()** if the return **dataType** is not a **html**?

```
$.ajax({
  type:       "GET",
  dataType:   "html",
  url:        "server.php",
  async:      true,

  beforeSend: function() {
  },

  success: function (returndata) {

    console.log(returndata); // I will get {"message":"something"}

  }

}).fail(function(jqXHR) { // this callback does not work

    alert("error"); 

});
```

For instance, in `server.php`,

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo '{"message":"something"}';
```

I will get  `{"message":"something"}` instead of `error`;

any ideas?

**edit:**

```
    $.ajax({
        type:       "GET",
        dataType:   "xml",
        url:        "server.php",
        async:      true,

    beforeSend: function() {
    },

    success: function (returndata) {

        console.log(returndata); // I will get {"message":"something"}

    }

    }).fail(function(jqXHR) { // this callback does not work

        alert("error"); 

    });
```

if I change the `dataType:` to  **"xml**", it will return the error (which is what I want) when it is expected xml - why does it not work in the same way for **"html"**?

Comment: set the header at server for the content type. If you are retrieving JSON why are you setting dataType as html in the first place?

Comment: thanks but I need processed it in jquery for whatever is returned from the server...

Comment: you have to set something properly, either server header or dataType. If not your expectations won't work. I can't see how you would be making requests andd not knowing the datatype that would be expected in return, otherwise how would you process responses?

Comment: I have set the server header to json but it is still valid in jquery when the dataType is expected to be hmtl...

Answer (score -1):

Check whether your server responds JSON as plain text encoding or application/JSON. If it is JSON, use error() method instead fail(). It will go to error method if content type mismatches. Here is an example.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "google.com",
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log("Err", err)
    }
});
```

Above code will work fine with error method and go to error if content type is html. Try this in your scenario.